# Warning: Attempt to read property "id" on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\test.php on line

Tags: php, arrays, json

i want to echo massages id but i getting 'Warning: Attempt to read property' error

This is my code

```
<?php

$result ='{"num":1,"message":{"cont":"test"},"messages":[{"id":"123","rct":999}],"status":"success"}';



$obj = json_decode($result);

echo $obj->messages->id;

?>
```

Comment: You need to look at the data. Try `$obj = json_decode($result, true);` (note the `, true`) and use `var_dump($obj)` or `var_export($obj, true)` to see what `messages` contains =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use like below because `messages` is also an array.

```
$result ='{"num":1,"message":{"cont":"test"},"messages":[{"id":"123","rct":999}],"status":"success"}';

$obj = json_decode($result,true);

echo $obj['messages'][0]['id'];
```